# выводит ошибку в xml

Tags: xml

мой код:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>

<!DOCTYPE students [
        <!ELEMENT students (student)>
        <!ELEMENT student (name, phoneNumber, country, city, street)>
        <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT phoneNumber (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT country (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT street (#PCDATA)>
        <!ATTLIST student id CDATA #REQUIRED]>

<students>

    <student id = "1">
        <name> Alex </name>
        <phoneNumber> 12345567 </phoneNumber>
        <country> The USA </country>
        <city> Denver </city>
        <street> 45 Main street </street>
    </student>

    <student id = "2">
        <name> Bob </name>
        <phoneNumber> 0906767 </phoneNumber>
        <country> Brasil </country>
        <city> Rio </city>
        <street> Main street </street>
    </student>
</students>
```

ошибка:

```
The attribute name must be specified in the attribute-list declaration for element "student".
```

Comment: В показанном примере не хватает закрывающей `>` после `#REQUIRED`. После её добавления парсер Visual Studio выдаёт предупреждение "The element 'students' has invalid child element 'student'" на второй элемент student - это логично, потому что в DTD указан только один элемент. Если сделать `(student*)`, то предупреждение исчезнет.

Comment: В каком редакторе пишете xml? Возможно, он не корректно выдаёт ошибки.

Comment: DTD — это технология 1990-х годов. Лучше начать использоватьXML Schema (XSD) вместо устаревшего DTD.  XSD стал стандартом еще в 2001 году.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov пишу  в intellij idea

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я пытался уже написать (student*) а также уже пробовал (student)* в общем я все методы пробовал

Comment: и вправду просто не хватало > после #Required